# Angular 7 template driven forms dynamic validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I am wondering how can I dynamically validate a form input that loops through an array using angular 7. For example if I had a first name and last name field it would have a min characters and a required validator, in the same array I could have an age input that would have a min-max and required validators, I was thinking maybe I should put them into a switch case and send the type to a validate function but I'm not too sure how I could do that

This is the code I have to loop through the array I store the type and name of the input

```js
/*Function to get the form*/
  getForm() {
    this.api.getForm(this.Param).subscribe(
        data  => {
          this.form = data;
          console.log(this.form);
        }
    );
  }
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let questions of form?.results[0].fields">
        <div class="md-form">
          <div class="col-12 p-3 ml-2">
            <span class="">{{questions.name}}</span><br />
            <input mdbInput type="{{questions.type}}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

I was also looking at reactive forms but I don't think it would work for what I need. Thank you in advance

Comment: I would definitely check reactive forms as they are more flexible then template driven forms.

Comment: You can achieve above thing without reactive forms. But that is not a good approach. As @robert said it is better to use reactive forms.